# err == errSecAuthFailed works fine on simulator but fails on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios5

I try to use

```
err == errSecAuthFailed
```

like here [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Listings/UI_Building_Blocks_CredentialImportController_m.html)

This works fine on simulator but fails on ios Device.. does someone know why??
As you can see on the link Apple also uses this. When I try this on device I get

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'errSecAuthFailed'
```

THX!

Comment: Is it a runtime or compile time error? What is your Base SDK version?

Comment: its a compile error, I use SDK 5.0 as Base SDK

Comment: Try adding #import <Security/SecBase.h> on top of the file where the error occurs. Just guessing, unfortunately.

Comment: @zrxq if you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `#import <Security/SecBase.h>` on top of the file where the error occurs.